# Time dilation, mass-energy equivalence, and implications for the passage of time

Tags: relativity, mass-energy, time-dilation, equivalence-principle

I'm an amateur physics enthusiast, and there is a question that's been in the back of my mind for some time that I haven't been able to answer on my own. First, I want to define a couple of terms and make sure my understanding isn't breaking down there before diving into my question on the implication.

First is the concept of [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation). When an object / person / particle is traveling at an extremely high velocity or is near a massive gravitational object, they experience time dilation relative to an outside observer. E.g., me and my twin brother are on earth, I travel in a rocket at the speed of light for one light-year, and return to earth at the same velocity, I experienced the trip as having been instant, but my twin brother is now two years older. Is this generally the correct understanding?

Next is the concept of [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) expressed in Einstein's famous equation, that mass is highly concentrated energy. So effectively, any piece of matter (an object with mass), is electrical in nature and simply condensed down so far that it appears solid to us as an observer in spacetime. Again, please correct me here if I'm wrong.

If both of these definitions are correct, it seems to me that all of us as observers are really just highly condensed balls of electrical energy, traveling at light speed at an atomic or subatomic level. Does that mean that, as physical objects, we are not experiencing time, but rather just *feel* we are experiencing time as higher level observers?

When I google "Time is an illusion", I get a lot about Carlo Rovelli, of which I've read a decent amount (although not his book The Order of Time, just a synopsis so far), but I don't really get a definitive answer. I would love any input at all to help me better understand this quandary. Thank you!

Comment: Don't confuse the basic time dilation effect (which is always symmetric) with the difference in four-pathlength (AKA interval) on different trajectories between two space-time events (what is explored by the twin paradox and can be aymmetric).

Comment: Electrons in most atoms are not particularly relativistic. Quarks inside of protons and neutrons are, but that has nothing to do with how time passes for *us*.

Comment: Relative to ourselves, we’re not moving at all. Relative to each other, we’re extremely non-relativistic. Relative to the Sun, or the center of the Milky Way, or the comoving frame of the expanding unverse, we’re also very non-relativistic. The idea that we’re zooming around near the speed of light and thus don’t experience time is misguided. You have to say moving *relative to what*. We *are* relativistic in some advanced alien’s rocket frame, but this has nothing to do with how *we* experience time.

Comment: "is electrical in nature and simply condensed down so far that it appears solid to us as an observer in spacetime" not sure what you mean by this, but it seems wrong.

Comment: to make the first comment more palatable: the example of time dilation you give involves acceleration, so, the observer that accelerates experiences less total time. But you can have time dilation between two observers at constant relative speed, which is symmetrical and in which case both see each other's clock's running slow.

Comment: I think the notion of time being only an illusion got you a down-vote, for the obvious reason that it ignores the various experimental proofs of Special Relativity (clocks in jets, etc.).  I brought you up to 0 because I'm intrigued by the notion of matter (including our own) being "concentrated energy", which offhand (without any looking into that notion) seems plausible enough to justify this comment.

Comment: You got downvoted for asking an honest question, no one understood what you were asking about, plus there are already votes to close your question as "a personal theory". Not the response you have hoped for, is it? Welcome to Physics SE :)

Comment: I hope my comment wasn't misunderstood; I mean, although most people interested in physics know SR is (or was) generally accepted partly because of experimental proofs, there's nothing to stop more recent experiments from changing that viewpoint, so any participant can legitimately ask whether time is, among people interested in physics, widely considered to be illusory. And, like I say, the OP provided a visualization which I really like:  By saying that, I wanted them to know that the site includes voters (like myself) who use physics notation only rarely and appreciate such aids.

Comment: The Rovelli book, which is recent, is extremely readable and good, but unconvincing on some points.

Comment: @Edouard "*I wanted them to know*" - Both of them on the photo?

Comment: No, only the one on the left (politically).

Answer (score 1):

> When an object / person / particle is traveling at an extremely high velocity or is near a massive gravitational object, they experience time dilation relative to an outside observer. [...] Is this generally the correct understanding?

It is commonly described that way, but it isn't a very good way of describing it. It's better to just say that elapsed time = length of worldline. Your movements over the course of your life can be drawn as a curve in spacetime, and the length of the curve is the length of your life. If you meet up with someone else at two points in your life, different amounts of time may have passed for the two of you between those points because the curves had different shapes between those points. The longer your worldline, the more room there is in it for the atomic processes that cause clocks to tick off the seconds, and human skin to accumulate wrinkles, and all of the other things that we associate with the passage of time. We don't notice differences of length most of the time because our worldlines are all almost straight and parallel to each other (we don't ever change speed by very much, on the scale of the speed of light).

The twin paradox is like the fact that if you drive in a straight line from A to B, while someone else takes a detour, their odometer will show a larger total distance traveled. The odometer that shows the larger distance will always be that of the car that changed direction at some point on the trip, simply because a straight line is the shortest distance between two points. In spacetime, because of the funny minus sign in the distance formula, it ends up being the other way around, and the straight line is longer instead of shorter, meaning that that person ends up older. Otherwise, every aspect of your intuition about the driving example should carry over to the worldline example.

> Next is the concept of mass-energy equivalence expressed in Einstein's famous equation, that mass is highly concentrated energy. So effectively, any piece of matter (an object with mass), is electrical in nature and simply condensed down so far that it appears solid to us as an observer in spacetime.

Mass-energy equivalence means that mass and energy are two names for the same thing. So mass isn't highly concentrated energy, it's just energy.

This is complicated by the fact that the words "mass" and "energy" are used in several different ways, that aren't all equivalent. For example "rest mass" and "rest energy" are the same as each other but not the same as "total energy." And "total energy" and "relativistic mass" are the same thing, even though they don't use the same word as a modifier, but most physicists avoid the term "relativistic mass" because it's considered confusing. This is just the English language being a mess as usual, and isn't really related to the underlying physical concepts.

I don't understand why you say "electrical" since electricity isn't related to anything else in this question.

> it seems to me that all of us as observers are really just highly condensed balls of [...] energy, traveling at light speed at an atomic or subatomic level.

This is sort of true. In modern physics, particles/fields (they are the same thing in quantum mechanics) that have mass can be understood as two separate massless fields that are coupled to each other. In the particle picture, you can to some extent imagine this as a particle that moves at the speed of light at every instant, but constantly reverses direction so that over longer time periods its average speed is less than the speed of light.

> Does that mean that, as physical objects, we are not experiencing time, but rather just feel we are experiencing time as higher level observers?

We really experience time.

To put it another way, if we don't experience time, then nothing does. Then there would be no use for the phrase "experiencing time" and instead you'd have to use "feel as though experiencing time" everywhere instead. Then we'd probably drop the "feel as though" part for brevity (which wouldn't create ambiguity since we weren't using "experiencing time" by itself any more), which would put us back where we started. There's no meaningful difference between something really being true and merely seeming in every way to be true.

The exact nature of our experience of time comes down to the ways in which the various fundamental particles we're made of interact with each other. This is very complicated in detail, but the key point is that it's the same everywhere (throughout the visible universe and all the way back to shortly after the big bang, as far as we can tell). So it's complicated but in a consistent way. That's why you can talk about the relative aging of two twins, for example: even though they're in different places between their two meeting points, the particle interactions that make them older are the same, and in the one with the longer worldline there's room for more of those interactions.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much for providing such a detailed and thoughtful response.

My follow-up question is to the beginning of your second-to-last paragraph. If we don't experience time, then nothing does. Is there anything to rule out the latter part of that sentence from being true, other than our subjective experience?

Comment: I have another follow-up question @benrg

>In the particle picture, you can to some extent imagine this as a particle that moves at the speed of light at every instant, but constantly reverses direction so that over longer time periods its average speed is less than the speed of light.

So, when we're thinking about particles (and not the quantum wave function and what happens when it fully collapses), is it fair to say the particle does not experience the passage of time (assuming it has a subjective experience)? And if so, doesn't that hold true for all the particles that compose "us"?